# Find duplicates in a coulmn and highlight row background color with alternate color

Tags: vba, excel

[image: Initial content]

[image: Processed content]

1. I want to highlight cell colors of rows (text is in column "A" to
   "G")with same color when value in "A" column is same and want to
   iterate same operation for all rows & apply alternate colors.
2. Also want to change font color to Red in 2 cells (of column "F" and
   "G") when there is text "Files are on EMEA server" in "F" column.

Comment: Please note that SO is not a "code for me" site. Try a code that 1) loops through all your rows. 2) As loop progreses, check actual and previous values in A column (this will work if data is ordered), and 3) if both values are the same, highlight entire row. Try googling `excel vba check two cell values` and `excel vba highlight row`.

Comment: This has been asked and answered too many times.  https://www.google.com/search?rls=com.microsoft%3Aen-US%3AIE-Address&q=vba+excel+highlight+row+if+text+is+found+in+cell&oq=vba+excel+highlight+row+if+text+is+found+in+cell&gs_l=serp.12..33i21k1.330561.346010.0.349229.50.41.0.0.0.0.518.5639.0j9j5j3j2j2.21.0..2..0...1.1.64.serp..29.17.4515...0j0i67k1j0i22i30k1j33i160k1.jlFdOctvKdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This macro alternates between 2 colours, changing when the value in column A changes.

```
Sub Highlighting()

Dim rw As Long
Dim lastrw As Long

' Define 2 different highlighting colours by their RGB values
Dim col1 As Long
Dim col2 As Long
col1 = RGB(255, 230, 180)
col2 = RGB(180, 230, 255)
' "Current" colour for highlighting
Dim col As Long
col = col1

With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    ' Get last row by last non-empty cell in column A
    lastrw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Cycle through column A
    For rw = 1 To lastrw
        ' Highlight row with current colour
        .Range("A" & rw & ":G" & rw).Interior.Color = col
        ' If column A value in next row is different, change colour
        If .Cells(rw + 1, 1).Value <> .Cells(rw, 1) Then
            ' Set to whichever colour it is not
            If col = col1 Then
                col = col2
            Else
                col = col1
            End If
        End If
    Next rw
End With

End Sub
```

Before:

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]

You should be able to change the font colour to red in certain cases, by inserting your own condition `If .Range("F" & rw).Value = "Files ... "` etc into the main `For` loop.

Comment: It's working nice, I got code to iterate through 1 to 52 index color but this is just cluttering whole content. So above code is nice to switch between just 2 colors. Also to highlight text in red colors, created new rule in conditional formatting. Added formula =$F1="Files are on EMEA server" and added =$F:$G to apply rule for.

Comment: If you wanted more colours, you look at creating an array of colours, and instead of the swap you could increase some counter, which specifies the element in the array. Depends how important multiple colours are to you, two colours is the simplest option for just separating regions...

Comment: Somehow when I'm executing above code from Personal.xlsb, it's not working.

Comment: @Samadhan a year later and a broad "it's not working" makes things tricky to diagnose. I'd advise asking another question with the issue details