# Macro from Personal.xlsb not working in other workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using below macro from `Personal.xlsb` (from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42808501/find-duplicates-in-a-coulmn-and-highlight-row-background-color-with-alternate-co/)) in other workbooks. But this is not highlighting any rows, no errors, nothing. When run in standalone workbooks it works fine.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub Highlighting()

Dim rw As Long
Dim lastrw As Long

' Define 2 different highlighting colours by their RGB values
Dim col1 As Long
Dim col2 As Long
col1 = RGB(255, 230, 180)
col2 = RGB(180, 230, 255)
' "Current" colour for highlighting
Dim col As Long
col = col1

With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    ' Get last row by last non-empty cell in column A
    lastrw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Cycle through column A
    For rw = 1 To lastrw
        ' Highlight row with current colour
        .Range("A" & rw & ":G" & rw).Interior.Color = col
        ' If column A value in next row is different, change colour
        If .Cells(rw + 1, 1).Value <> .Cells(rw, 1) Then
            ' Set to whichever colour it is not
            If col = col1 Then
                col = col2
            Else
                col = col1
            End If
        End If
    Next rw
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change,

```
With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
```

... to,

```
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
```

That will allow you to use it on the currently active workbook/worksheet. ThisWorkbook refers to the Personal.xlsb the code resides in (e.g. **This**Workbook)

Answer (score 1):

That's because in the macro you are using `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet` so the code will only work in your `Personal.xlsb` workbook.

Replace the line...

```
With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
```

**WITH**

```
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
```

And the code will work on any workbook which is active.

Comment: @Experimenter You're welcome! Thanks for the feedback.