# Alternate rows coloring in Excel using Epplus

Tags: c#, .net, excel, linq, epplus

I have multiple rows which I colored with White and dark grey. an example for alternate rows:

[image]

The code I used:

```
            //end.Row is the last row of the excel file
            for (var row = 1; row <= end.Row; row++)
            {
                int pos = row % 2;

                ExcelRow rowRange = BaseSheet.Row(row);
                ExcelFill RowFill = rowRange.Style.Fill;
                RowFill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;

                    if (pos == 0)
                    {
                        RowFill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(233, 233, 233));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        RowFill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255));
                    }
            }
```

and it works as intended.
But in my case here I have some identical names not counting the numbers at the end  like (nameB_1 , nameB_2). I was able to find and group them with:

```
            List<string> BaseLines = new List<string>();

            for (int row = 1; row <= end.Row; row++)
            {
                //get the filename column
                string fileName = BaseSheet.Cells[row, 1].Value.ToString();

                BaseLines.Add(fileName.Substring(0, fileName.Length - 2));
            }
                        
             var duplicateIndexes = BaseLines
            .Select((t, i) => new { Index = i, Text = t })
            .GroupBy(g => g.Text)
            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
            .SelectMany(g => g, (g, x) => x.Index);
```

It returns them as follows:
{Index = 3, Text = "nameB"}
{Index = 4, Text = "nameB"}

I want to do alternate rows coloring but making an exception in the case there is a two duplicate rows(the identical row will always be after the original one) so that the second row will be the same color like in this image:

[image]

I tried this:

```
 for (var row = 1; row < end.Row; row++)
            {
                int pos = row % 2;
                ExcelRow rowRange = BaseSheet.Row(row+1);
                ExcelFill RowFill = rowRange.Style.Fill;
                RowFill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                

                //get the filename column
                string fileName = BaseSheet.Cells[row, 1].Value.ToString();

                //Get the filename without the last two characters to find continued lines
                string NewfileName = fileName.Substring(0, fileName.Length - 2);
                
                //To find the first instance to take the color from
                var FirstDuplicate = duplicateIndexes .Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 0);

                bool isduplicate= false;
                foreach (var item in FirstDuplicate)
                {

                    if (item == row)
                    {
                        isduplicate= true;

                    }
                }

                if (isduplicate== false)
                {
                    if (pos == 0)
                    {
                        RowFill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(233, 233, 233));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        RowFill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //Get the color of the first instance
                    var Hexcolor = BaseSheet.Cells[row, 1].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Rgb;
                    Color RGBColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#" + Hexcolor);
                    
                    //Set the color to the current duplicate
                    RowFill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(RGBColor);
                }


            }
```

The problem with this approach that the next line that is not duplicated still has it's old color
[image]

**So in summary: I want to do alternate rows coloring with the exception to duplicate lines to have the same color but still make the rest of the lines maintain the order of coloring.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer from a similar question in VBA here :https://stackoverflow.com/a/42809651/8494981

I have modified it for my current situation by replacing the whole for loop code with this method:

```
        public void ColorAlternateRows(ExcelWorksheet sheet)
        {
        int row;
        int lastrow;

        Color color1 = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(233, 233, 233);
        Color color2 = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);

        // "Current" colour for highlighting
        Color currentColor;
        currentColor = color1;


        lastrow = sheet.Dimension.End.Row;

        for (row = 1; row < lastrow; row++)
        {
            //Define the pattern type.
            //The range here is all rows within the excel sheet from A to G column
            sheet.Cells["A" + row + ":G" + row].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;

            //Set the color of the row
            sheet.Cells["A" + row + ":G" + row].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(currentColor);

            //get the filename in column A for the first line and second line
            string firstLine = sheet.Cells[row, 1].Value.ToString();
            string secondLine = sheet.Cells[row+1, 1].Value.ToString();

            //get the original filename without the additional suffix numbering
            string firstLineWithoutSuffix = firstLine.Substring(0, firstLine.Length - 2);
            string SecondLineWithoutSuffix = secondLine.Substring(0, secondLine.Length - 2);

            // If column A value in next row is different, change colour
            if (SecondLineWithoutSuffix != firstLineWithoutSuffix)
            {
                    // Set to whichever colour it is not
                    if (currentColor == color1)
                        currentColor = color2;
                    else
                        currentColor = color1;
            }
        }
    }
```